# Absence of ellipsis in tag excerpts in the Tags page

Tags: bug, tags, design

I was reading through the tags in SO when I noticed that the overflow in the excerpts is hidden.

[image: Tags page]

Upon inspecting a tag (java in this case); the excerpt text has ellipsis *(...)* but it overflows and the `overflow` is set to `hidden`:

```
#tags_list .excerpt {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Is this an already reported bug?

Comment: We definitely don't want to change `overflow: hidden;` to something else or we'll have a bunch of scroll bars on that page. I would argue this is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: I am lost, i see no free hand red circles here

Comment: @TylerH my issue with the predetermined ellipses is that they're ineffective in **Responsiveness** as well. When I resize the browser window to a more mobile friendly size the ellipses are there but so is almost a full line of white space.

Answer (score 1):

Those ellipses you see are just a pre-determined character count breakpoint, cropped server-side. There's no telling exactly how many characters will fit that excerpt block.

You can't reliably have multiline text end in ellipsis automatically (through CSS), when hiding text overflow.

So, one solution would be to reduce the character count before the content gets cut off, but I see no real reason to do so:
Yes, this would make the ellipsis visible, but it would also reduce the amount of content that's visible.

Comment: *"You can't reliably have multiline text end in ellipsis automatically (through CSS)"* Sounds like a practical programming problem that someone could ask about on a popular programming Q&A site.

Comment: @CodyGray: Trust me, people have. Every single solution either ends in a visible movement of the beak point, or a incorrectly placed set of ellipsis.

Comment: You guys should try using jQuery. It's great and does all things.

Comment: Yea, I heard it could do magic things :D